# Pass my Coins variable to another Scene

Tags: xcode, swift, struct, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I want to pass my varible from the GameScene.swift to the CoinScene.swift. I know i can use struct but i don't know how to use it. Everytime i try it, it doesn't work. In the GameScene.swift i have the variable coins:

```
var coins = Int()
```

in the CoinScene.swift i use iAP and if the User buy 100 Coins it has to update.
There i use the function:

```
func addCoins100() {
    coins + 100

}
```

but this wouldn't work because theres no connection between this two "coins".
Where and how should i use the struct or is there an other way to do this?

I set this code in the top of GameScene.swift:

```
struct coins {
static var coinVariable = "coins"
```

}

And then this in the CoinsScene.swift:

```
let coins = coins.coinVarible
```

This is not working. Do anyone have an Idea to fix that?
Im a beginner and not very good but hungry to learn. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also:

**in GameScene.swift:**

```
static var coins = Int()
```

**in CoinsScene.swift**

```
func addCoins100() {
    GameScene.coins + 100
}
```

Be careful with this approach

Comment: It works with this code. Thank you very much. But why i need to be careful with this approach?

Comment: Because it's close like the global variable

Comment: In the GameScene.swift it gives me errors all the time if i replace my variable coins with the static variable. How can i fix that?
ERROR: (Static member coins cannot be used on instance of type GameScene)

Comment: Because you can not use it as instance variable. Also in GameScene you must call the variable with GameScene.coins

Comment: Now i understand and it works fine. Thank you very much Simone! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `coinVariable` to the string coins, not the variable coins. Here's what I would do:

```
struct coins{
    var coinCount = 0
}
```

Then when you want to set coins in CoinScene.swift use

```
func addCoins100() {
    coins.coinCount += 100
}
```

Whenever you want to access the coins just use `coins.coinCount`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With this code coinCount = 0. But the coinCount has to be the same from my NSuserdefault. So would it work if i write:<br/>  var coinCount = "\(coins)"

Comment: 0 was just there because I assumed the player would start with 0. Make it whatever you want.

Comment: Unfortenately it doesn`t work anymore. In the CoinScene.swift it give me an error (Instance member `coinCount`cannot be used on type `coins`) What`s wrong?

Comment: You need to make an instance of the struct for it to work.